# joomla 3.4 transfer to other server

Tags: joomla, transfer

I have transferred Joomla 3.4 (from a cPanel backup) to Plesk. The site is 8GB.

I have changed the permissions for folders and files. I can login normally to the /administrator

At the front end I get this error message -

> Notice: Use of undefined constant JPATH_BASE - assumed 'JPATH_BASE' in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/defines.php on line 12 Notice: Use of undefined constant JPATH_BASE - assumed 'JPATH_BASE' in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/defines.php on line 22 Notice: Use of undefined constant JPATH_BASE - assumed 'JPATH_BASE' in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/defines.php on line 23 Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/includes/defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/index.php on line 31 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/index.php on line 31

Also I have one other Joomla site to the same server, which loaded as expected without an error.

I need help in figuring out how to fix this error.

Comment: Do you actually have a defines.php folder in your site root? Does it definte JPATH_ROOT?

Answer (score 0):

are the account constants in configuration.php file updated to a new server? additionally check your php.ini file if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "defines.php" file was moved to root path.

It should be in "\includes" path.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/includes

Move(Crop/Paste) it into "\includes" folder.